# Why does JSON.stringify display in a different order than iterating through an array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm writing a comment system and I want to have the option to sort by most upvotes which I'm doing in a php file and then echoing the data to JavaScript.

When I log this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(commentHopper));
```

the comments are in the right order with the upvotes as the following: 900, 500, 300, 0, 0

But when I iterate through the array like this:

```
for (var n = 0; n < commentHopper.length; n++) {
           console.log(commentHopper[n]);
}
```

the results are in this order: 0, 300, 900, 0, 500

Comment: Are you sure `commentHopper` is an array?  It could be an "array-like" object.  How are you creating it?k

Comment: Show us your data structure.

Comment: What you call an array in php isn't always an array in javascript. Objects have no guarenteed order.

Comment: If I do console.log(commentHopper) I get this:

[Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7]]

Comment: What does `console.log(commentHopper.constructor === Array);` show you?

Comment: Can you show us the php generated javascript? (not the php, ctrl+shift+u)

Comment: @RocketHazmat function Array() { [native code] }

Comment: @cantread: Ok, so it is an array, and not any kind of "array-like" object or something.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely dealing with an object not an array.

Try `console.log(typeof commentHopper)`

If you want to go through the object "in order" you can use a [for/in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement.

```
for(var key in commentHopper){
    console.log(commentHopper[key]);
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, `typeof []` returns `"object"`.  This won't tell you if it's an array or not.  (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)  You need to check `commentHopper.constructor`.